# How to pull variable from one form to another form on same web page

Tags: php

I have a php web page that has 2 separate forms on it that both show results at the bottom of the page. The first form uses one drop-down menu (titled Quickshow) with 6 choices that filters the results when selected, with the top choice being the default selection when the page is opened. The second form has 6 drop-down menus, each with multiple choices, that filters the results once the "Filter Results" button is clicked.

My problem is when the second form is used, it is using the default selection from the first form instead of staying with the selected choice from the first form. I understand the code that is making the first choice the default, and also allowing it to change for the first form, but how do I keep (call?) the optional choices for the second form? Below is the code being used for both forms. The first part is the web (.php) page portion, the second part is on the template (.tpl) page that is being pulled over to the web page. I didn't write the pages, but am trying to fix the filter on it.

**.php page**
function enumRequests() {

```
$getQuickShow = 1;

if (!$_REQUEST['feature_quickshow'] == '') {
        $getQuickShow = (int)$_REQUEST['feature_quickshow'];
}

$quickShow = eval(quickShow($getQuickShow));
$whereArray[] = (string)$quickShow;

if ($_REQUEST['resultsFiltered']) {
    $quickShow = eval(quickShow($getQuickShow));
    //$whereArray[] = (string)$quickShow;
    foreach ($_REQUEST AS $key => $val) {
        if ($val) {
            $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
            if (strpos($key, 'fld_') === 0) {
                $newKey = str_replace('fld_','',$key);
                $whereFragment = "{$newKey} = '{$val}'";
                $whereArray[] = (string)$whereFragment;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**.tpl page**

Quick Show:
[@quickshow]

Thanks in advance for any help I receive with this.

Comment: Why not have both forms post to different scripts? So the fist form can post to post1.php and the second form can post to post2.php. That way you can handle the post data individually.

Answer (score 0):

you can always refer to `document.forms[1].mytxt.value = document.forms[0].utxt.value`

Comment: Which page would I add this to, the .php or the .tpl?

Comment: One last question (which I should have asked before): does the line go at the top of the page, after the 'function' statement, or in one of the 'if' statements?

Comment: you need to place the line where you are starting to play with the second form's dropdown

Comment: do I need to add anything onto the 'Form Action=' line (<form action="index.php?module=featurehub") of the second form to send a value for the variable from the first form?